# How to capture values from url?

Tags: php

I am collecting customer data on one page and then taking them to the next page where they select the services that they want.
I wish to pass customer name and customer ref no to the next page when they are selecting the services.

I pass the value like this
`http://www.mywebsite.com/services.php?name={$cust_name}&ref={$ref_no}`

What will be the PHP code to capture them in the `services.php` page

Comment: then just use `$_GET` variables for that, then use the corresponding index like `name` and `ref` in `services.php`

Comment: Thanks. The parameters in both forms should have same variable name?

Comment: not necessarily, it does not need to have the same variable name, but you need to use the same index name to access them in `$_GET`, just look at the answers below

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get values from URL using `$_GET` global array.

i.e

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
```

Answer (score 0):

URL to visit:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/services.php?name=john&ref=1
```

Code in `services.php`:

```
$cust_name = $_GET["name"]; //john
$ref_no= $_GET["ref"]; //1
```

Answer (score 0):

On services.php, just use `$_GET["name"]` and `$_GET["ref"]` to refer to these variables.

Answer (score 0):

if you have this type of link

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/services.php?name=anyName&ref=1234
```

then you can get variable like this

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
$ref=$_GET['ref'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the URL paremeters with $_GET.

```
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
```

See http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php

Be careful using data like customer name in URL parameters. Somebody could just enter another customer's name and maybe see data which he/she should not be allowed to.

Comment: Thanks. I won't be storing anything captured on services page. Will capture data and pass it through email.